# VB Script to prevent Outlook client to add a certain number of recipients per message

Tags: vba, vbscript, outlook

I want a script through which anyone could add only a particular number of recipients that I allow them to send.

For example:

I want to limit my Outlook client to add only 25 recipients and as soon as they add the 26th recipient it will automatically give an error "You cannot add more than 25 recipients", and it will exit the New mail.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please add more details/code to your post to further help us to help you with your issue.

Comment: This isn't a homework question is it...? Please post what you have already tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no event in Outlook which fires if you add a new recipient. There is however a event which fires when a E-Mail is being sent.

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim arrTo() As String
    Dim arrCC() As String
    Dim arrBCC() As String
    arrTo = Split(Item.To, ";")
    arrCC = Split(Item.CC, ";")
    arrBCC = Split(Item.BCC, ";")
    itemcount = UBound(arrTo) + 1 + UBound(arrCC) + 1 + UBound(arrBCC) + 1
    If (itemcount > 25) Then
        MsgBox("You cannot add more than 25 recipients.")
        Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub
```

This code executes when the user presses send. It then checks if there are more than 25 recipients and if so, it will cancel he delivery and print a message.

Answer (score 1):

When a recipient is added, `MailItem.PropertyChange` event will fire 3 times with the "To", "CC", and "BCC" arguments.